# Installing matplotlib on Mac 10.9 for python3

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.4

I've tried everything and seem to have installed matplotlib, but on the default mac python 2.x and not the python 3 that I currently use. Is there a way to install matplotlib (and the other python science tools) into python 3 and not to the default 2.7?

Comment: use pip for python 3  to install, something like `pip3 install matplotlib`

Comment: Thank you! I did pip before but not 'pip3'. Seriously thanks a lot!